# Building Xamarin iOS on Mac fails using msbuild with mono_os_mutex_lock (succeeds from VS for Mac)

Tags: macos, build, xamarin.ios, msbuild, mono

**Background**

I'm trying a new route for building my xamarin projects with my CI. I have a new project which successfully builds on the PC through VS connected to a Mac. It also successfully builds on the Mac using Visual Studio for Mac.

**The problem**

It fails when I try to build from the command-line (terminal) using msbuild with the error:

```
mono_os_mutex_lock: pthread_mutex_lock failed with "Invalid Argument" (11)
```

**The Research**

I've scoured the internet and found some recent issues with this error that were indicated as being resolved in Mono 5.0.1 (which I have), such as:

- [peverify fails on FSharp.Core.dll with mono_os_mutex_lock: pthread_mutex_lock failure](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56177)
- [peverify is broken again](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43786)
- One other I can't remember or find now (but had no useful information, and might have pointed back to the above links)

**Other Notes**

I have other builds using the vsts build agent that continue to work, although they are using the VSTS Xamarin and Android build tasks. I'm wondering if I'm missing some environment settings or something else. I do not currently have a scaled down project that can be tested. I'm up to date when I check in VS for Mac on all the Xamarin bits.

Comment: This turned out to only be an issue when using the propertychanged.fody package. Removing the package removed the errors. "When I get time" I'm planning to submit a sample project to them and the Xamarin team. Odd that it works in VS for Mac, but not from msbuild on mac.

Comment: Hi Duane, I'm encontering this issue. Did you follow up with the Xamarin team and/or the fody team? Was there a fix for this that still allowed you to use fody? I'm using it to add INotifyPropertyChanged automatically and don't want to remove it if it's not necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @mikelowe, no, I didn't solve it. got some feedback from the xamarin team about using the beta channel mono (at the time) but that did not help. And due to time constraints we pulled fody from our solution (sad). I never got around to making the repro project to submit, although it should be pretty easy to create.